# Regex not operator

Tags: javascript, regex

I need to use a regex to pull a value out a url domain that will exclude everything but the host (ex: wordpress) and domain type (ex .com). The urls are dynamic and contain 2-3 values for each result (www.example.com or example.org). I am trying to use this expression, but I am only getting back the first letter of every item I am attempting to exclude:

**Expresssion**

```
(?!wordpress|com|www)(\w+|\d+)
```

**String**

> example.wordpress.com

**Results**

1. example
2. ordpress
3. om
4. Desired Result

example

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I am really having a hard time understanding you question. What is the pattern for the input, and what is you you want returned as a match for each URL?

Answer (score 3):

Anchor your regular expression:

```
\b(?!wordpress|com|www)(\w+|\d+)\b
```

You might also want to consider whether `(\w+|\d+)` is really what you mean. `\w` already includes digits. Also, there are other characters allowed in URLs such as `-`. Do you need to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

If I was to do thing like that, I would take advantage of the format of the url: anything (dot) 2nd-level-domain (dot) 1st-level-domain:

`^(?<level3>.*)[.]?(?<level2>.+)[.](?<level1>.+)$`

Answer (score 0):

Is it so that you are only after what is after the domain part??

```
(/\/(?!\/).*?\/(.*)/).exec("http://www.google.com/sdfsdf/fdsff")[1]
// returns sdfsdf/fdsff
```